# Как в woocommerce сделать отправку писем о заказе на разные почты в зависимости от зоны доставки?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Столкнулся с задачей сделать отправку письма о заказе в woocommerce таким образом, что бы при выборе зоны доставки менялась почта получателя на почту конкретной зоны.
[image: Схема]

Все запросы в гугле ни к чему не привели, единственное, что нашел

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);
  function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
  $recipient = $recipient . ', me@myemail.com';
  return $recipient;
}
```

И то, этот фильтр не для магазина, а для покупателя (подтверждение заказа).

Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с подобной задачей? Был бы признателен, если бы поделились опытом)